# Protect escaped chars from pattern ending

Tags: regex

Assuming you have a pattern "A<(.*?)>"

Using Java, Pattern, Matcher, matcher.find() method as an example.

- As input you have `"A<v1>"`  --> Pattern is matching and the group(1) is `"v1"`
- As input you have `"A<v1>v2>"`  --> Pattern is matching and the group(1) is `"v1"` due to "?" turning ".*" to non-greedy.

Assuming a user want to protect the input like:
  `"A<v1\>v2>"`, so the pattern should match and the group(1) has the value `"v1>v2"`.

So the pattern should stay "non-greedy", but a escaped chars is protect and be part of the value (grouping).

The pattern processing is done in a "while" loop, so I want to find all occurences of the pattern in the input. So the pattern should accept a less as possible (non-greedy), but can handle the "escaped" char (here: the ">" is my ending of the pattern)).

Any hints.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept `\>` as a valid expression to match:

```regex
A<((\\>|.)*?)>
```

The group `(\\>|.)` will match either the characters `\>` or, if that doesn't match, `.`. The order is important, because `\>` will match two characters while `.` only matches one, meaning that `.` will gobble up the `\` character if it appears first.

To illustrate:

```
A <   v 1 \> v 2     >
| |   | | |  | |     |
A < ( . . \> . . )*? >
```

However, the resulting match would be `v1\>v2`, so you'll need to do some processing after the fact to convert `\>` to `>`

If you wanted to go even further and allow escaping the `\` character, you could use a character class like so:

```regex
A<((\\[>\\]|.)*?)>
```

Which would match the following:

```
A<v1\\>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks. You saved my day :-)